# Material UI AutoComplete setting value to 0

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have been stuck on this bug for a while and not sure what is going on, please can you help if you have a second. Thank you.

Issue:

- I am trying to use the autocomplete component with material ui and react-hook-form, but whenever I select a option from the dropdown menu and log the value from reack-hoom-form watch function, I get 0 being logged even though the options are strings.

I have replicated the issue on codesandbox see link below
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-not-working-her-weg6e?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Your code sandbox was a mess with lots of unwanted code unrelated to the question. I have cleaned it up.

1. Initialize state -  `const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");`
2. OnChange, update the state

   ```
   onChange={(e, data) => {
        setInputValue(data.year);
      }}
   ```

Here is a working code which logs the value of selected resolution code
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-not-working-her-forked-cqxz4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, checked it out, this works fine, however, if I wrap the autocomplete inside a controller component (see example 1 below)  and try to setValue for that form name it still sets the value to 0.
@Kal Thank you for your time and assistance in advance!
I have created another codesand box where I wrap the autocomplete with controller and try to set the value for the form, but its gets set to 0 and is not being updated.


See codesandbox [link]https://codesandbox.io/s/material-not-working-her-weg6e?file=/src/App.js:749-1215

Comment: Sounds like a new question different from your original question :)

Comment: Yes, apologies about that, still getting used to asking the correct questions and understanding the issue. 
When I posted the question on the thread, I was still playing around and trying to figure out different ways to solve it. Then I found out it has to do with the controller. Thanks @Kal :)

Comment: What are you using the controller for in your app? React-hook-form seems to work even without controller in their demo. Personally I like to create my own validation in handleSubmit and use a nice snackbar type message that pops up from the bottom - https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/. Do you need react-hook-form for validation?

Comment: Also take a look at the popular - https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: We are wrapping all our textfields, dates and autocomplete with the controller. 
I get that react-hook-form works without it and could be tempting to remove it just for this problem, but we are wrapping all text-field and date pickers with the controller and it works well. We do this so we can easily refer to each form field by giving it a name prop which we can then access from the form values like this
const {make} = watch() // watch comes from react-hook-form useForm method.

Component looks like this
<Controller name="make" as={AutoComplete ...(can be text field/date picker/>} />

Comment: I dont have a ready answer to your new question about controller without digging into this myself. May be ask a question with `controller` specified in the title and the question body and someone who has used it for a similar use case may answer.  Good luck.